# Laravel email notification blade component is not rendering properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My Laravel email notification prints blade component names instead of html element names in the output. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #ffffff; color: #718096; height: 100%; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
<:message style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">

# Hi,



<:button :url="$actionUrl" :color="$color" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
Open
</:button>


See ya!


<subcopy style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
If you're having trouble clicking the "Open" button, copy and paste the URL below
into your web browser: <span class="break-all" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; word-break: break-all;">[http://localhost:3000/](http://localhost:3000/)</span>
</subcopy>
</:message>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, there is a `<:message>` and a `<:button>` component in the output, but they should probably have been replaced with some html.

How can I fix this? I've tried publishing the notification views but that doesn't do anything. This is Laravel 9.

**Edit**
I understand there must be something wrong with my app, but I can reproduce this issue by doing the following (in my app):

1. Generate a new notification with `php artisan make:notification MyNotification --markdown=emails.my-notification`.
2. In `routes/web.php`, add:

```
Route::get("/test-notification", function () {
    return (new \App\Notifications\MyNotification)->toMail(new \App\User);
});
```

The output when visiting `/test-notification` in a browser is (if you view the source of the page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #ffffff; color: #718096; height: 100%; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
<:message style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
# Introduction

The body of your message.

<:button :url="''" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
Button Text
</:button>

Thanks,<br>
Laravel
</:message>
</body></html>
```

However, if I follow those two steps in a fresh Laravel 9 application, the output instead is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Laravel</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light">
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.inner-body {
width: 100% !important;
}

.footer {
width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.button {
width: 100% !important;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #ffffff; color: #718096; height: 100%; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">

<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; background-color: #edf2f7; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td class="header" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://localhost" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #3d4852; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">
<img src="https://laravel.com/img/notification-logo.png" class="logo" alt="Laravel Logo" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; max-width: 100%; border: none; height: 75px; max-height: 75px; width: 75px;">
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<!-- Email Body -->
<tr>
<td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; background-color: #edf2f7; border-bottom: 1px solid #edf2f7; border-top: 1px solid #edf2f7; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; border: hidden !important;">
<table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px; background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #e8e5ef; border-radius: 2px; border-width: 1px; box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.025), 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.015); margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px;">
<!-- Body content -->
<tr>
<td class="content-cell" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; max-width: 100vw; padding: 32px;">
<h1 style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #3d4852; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Hello!</h1>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">The introduction to the notification.</p>
<table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%; margin: 30px auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<a href="http://localhost:50027" class="button button-primary" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; text-decoration: none; background-color: #2d3748; border-bottom: 8px solid #2d3748; border-left: 18px solid #2d3748; border-right: 18px solid #2d3748; border-top: 8px solid #2d3748;">Notification Action</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Thank you for using our application!</p>
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Regards,<br>
Laravel</p>


<table class="subcopy" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; border-top: 1px solid #e8e5ef; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 25px;">
<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 14px;">If you're having trouble clicking the "Notification Action" button, copy and paste the URL below
into your web browser: <span class="break-all" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; word-break: break-all;"><a href="http://localhost:50027" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; color: #3869d4;">http://localhost:50027</a></span></p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative;">
<table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 570px;">
<tr>
<td class="content-cell" align="center" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; max-width: 100vw; padding: 32px;">
<p style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; position: relative; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; color: #b0adc5; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">© 2023 Laravel. All rights reserved.</p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So somewhere in my application, the resolution of blade components in markdown emails is disabled. I have run `artisan view:clear` to clear the cache. Maybe there are other caches in play?

I can also pinpoint that this problem was introduced when I upgraded Laravel from 9.34.0 to 9.35.0. I.e., with 9.34.0 the components resolve just fine, but in 9.35.0 and onwards I get the behavior described above.

Comment: Can you share your blade file?

Comment: It's a notification. It uses the blade template from the vendor directory.

Comment: you would have blade template over here `resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php:`

Comment: There is no `resources/views/vendor/notifications` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but I will own my mistake in the hope it helps someone else. In an edit to my question I wrote

> So somewhere in my application, the resolution of blade components in markdown emails is disabled.

Turns out I actually have this in my AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...

        Blade::withoutComponentTags();

        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

So yeah, I explicitly disabled blade component tags and then forgot about it... Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

> To display a component, you may use a Blade component tag within one
> of your Blade templates. Blade component tags start with the string x-
> followed by the kebab case name of the component class:
>
> ```
> <x-button/>
>  
> <x-user-profile/>
> ```
>
> If the component class is nested deeper within the app/View/Components
> directory, you may use the . character to indicate directory nesting.
> For example, if we assume a component is located at
> app/View/Components/Inputs/Button.php, we may render it like so:
>
> ```
> <x-inputs.button/>
> ```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#rendering-components